# VBA if and vlookup on multiple columns

Tags: vba, macros

I have two tables (Table1 & Table2). Table1 has values as TRUE or FALSE. Last cell is the desired output. I want that if all values in Table1 are FALSE, my Output column should write 0. If any cell is TRUE then it should lookup in Table2 for the corresponding number and return the outcome either as 1 or 3. I am unable to write any code for this. Your help would be appreciated. Tables are attached as image.

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

Answer (score 0):

**No VBA** from me, just direct formula with the following formula:

```
=MAX(INDEX($B$10:$B$13,MATCH($A$1:$D$1,$A$10:$A$13,0))*(--(A2:D2)))
```

You can adapt it for your VBA code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for a macro, if you can help.